# Angular Material validation without reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am struggling to  get the Angular Material forms validation work with  Angular Template forms. All examples are working with reactive forms only.

I am generating template Angular Material template forms in the following form:

```
<mat-form-field *ngSwitchCase="'text'" class="entity-form-field" appearance="outline">
  <input matInput [placeholder]="field.title" [value]="getValue(field)" 
    (change)="setValue(field, $event)" [required]="field.req" [id]="field.id">
  <mat-error *ngIf="fieldInvalid(field)">{{getErrorMessage(field)}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Both *fieldInvalid* and *getErrorMessage* are working fine, so the field error message should be visible. If I change it to a different tag then it will be visible:

`<p *ngIf="fieldInvalid(field)">{{getErrorMessage(field)}}</p>`

I understand that the Reative Forms have to change the state of the input to make change it's style to make it visible.

Is there a way to do the same with simple Template Forms?
I could probably also apply the Angular Material error styles, but I can't find the documentation.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm up against a similar issue.

Comment: If we're talking about client side validation, there's a set of built-in validators. You're free to write the custom one via `@Directive`. Then it's possible to access the errors via template variables such as `name.perstine` for `#name` etc. `<mat-errors>` should work as well [doc](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#template-driven-validation)

Comment: @WildDev People who do not use reactive forms tend to be the people who have a different validation solution (e.g. my validation happens through json schemas, as we need to use it in a lot of different places) and getting that to work with "the angular form" way gives rise to a *lot* of bloat.

Answer (score 5):

Solved this after reading Angular doc (https://angular.io/guide/forms):

```
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="scenario.name" name="scenarioName" 
#scenarioName="ngModel"
placeholder="Scenario name" class="form-control"
required minlength="3">
<mat-error [hidden]="scenarioName.valid">Scenario name should have at least 3 symbols</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

So the key was #scenarioName="ngModel" bit which then Angular uses to assign valid/invalid properties that you can then use for mat-error visisbility.

Comment: How can you check if there are any errors programmatically when doing validation like this without a form? When doing this, the validation works fine from the user perspective but I cannot check if there are any validation errors so the user can still just submit even if there are validation errors.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a pure solution, but simple and feasable workaround. *Mat-hint* can easily be styled as error and conditionally shown only in error state:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Label</mat-label>
  <input matInput ...>
  <mat-hint class="error-hint" *ngIf="fieldInvalid(field)">{{getErrorMessage(field)}}</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

And the *error-hint* class:

```
.error-hint {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Except the label and underline should also turn red